# modelSim VHDL some input signals not appearing in object window

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I'm working on a turbo decoding system on vhdl. The system is not outputing the expected result so I need to debug it. In the architecture of my decoder system, I'm instantiating the blocks components as follows:

```
inst_decoder : for i in 0 to MAX_BSIZE -1 generate

  signal llrs_valid_upper: std_logic ;
  signal llrs_in_upper : llrs_rec;
  signal llrs_valid_lower: std_logic;
  signal llrs_in_lower: llrs_rec;


begin


  -- get the corresponding llrs from the input_llr buffer, and set the llrs_valid to 1
  llrs_in_upper.system_llr <= input_llr(i); 
  llrs_in_upper.parity_llr <= input_llr(MAX_BSIZE+NUM_ENC_REGS+i);
  llrs_in_upper.extr_llr <= extr_upper_int(i);
  llrs_valid_upper <= input_llr_valid;

  inst_upper_algorithmic_block: component tcdec_algorithmic_block
    port map (
      clk => clk,
        rst => rst,
          en  => en_int,

          alpha_in => alpha_upper_int(i),
          beta_in => beta_upper_int(i+1),

          llrs_valid => llrs_valid_upper,
          llrs_in  => llrs_in_upper,

          init    => init,
          alpha_init => ALL_ZEROS,
          beta_init => ALL_ZEROS,

          extr_out  => extr_lower_int(de_il_table(i)),
          alpha_out => alpha_upper_int(i+1),
          beta_out => beta_upper_int(i)

    );

  llrs_in_lower.system_llr <= input_llr(il_table(i));
  llrs_in_lower.parity_llr <= input_llr(2*(MAX_BSIZE+NUM_ENC_REGS) + NUM_ENC_REGS + i);
  llrs_in_lower.extr_llr <= extr_lower_int(i);
  llrs_valid_lower <= input_llr_valid;

  inst_lower_algorithmic_block: component tcdec_algorithmic_block
    port map(
      clk => clk,
      rst => rst,
      en => en_int,

      alpha_in => alpha_lower_int(i),
      beta_in => beta_lower_int(i+1),

      llrs_valid => llrs_valid_lower,
      llrs_in => llrs_in_lower,

      init => init,
      alpha_init => ALL_ZEROS,
      beta_init => ALL_ZEROS,

      extr_out => extr_upper_int(il_table(i)),
      alpha_out => alpha_lower_int(i+1),
      beta_out => beta_lower_int(i)

    );  
end generate inst_decoder;
```

When trying to debug the design, some of the input signal for each block are not appearing, namely the rst signal, the llrs_in, the llrs_valid...

To make it weirder, the first block (for i=0, inst_upper_algorithmic_block) has all its input, the rest don't.

I tried restaring the computer, restarting modelSim, closing and opening the project with no use.

I tried also running the design with and without optimization, got the same result.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot and the modelsim version number.

Comment: Make sure you simulate without optimization: -novopt on the command line when you start the simulation or uncheck Optimization when you go through the GUI. It may simply be that rst and other signals have a constant value in your testbench, so they get optimized away and therefore cannot be shown in simulation.

Answer (score -1):

Try compiling your design with `-novopt -O0`.
Additionally, I believe you can manually add signals to the waveform via Tcl commands (need to test, as far as I remember, this works for signals missing from the object list.):

```
add wave "sim:/<testbench_name>/inst_upper_algorithmic_block/clk"
```

ModelSim will either add the signal or tell you why it can't be added.

But since things, "started to work", I believe you "fixed" your design (sometimes ModelSim doesn't helps us understanding what is wrong).

Answer (score -1):

Delete the 'simulation' directory -> close modelsim -> reopen and simulate.

It showed the missing signals for me.

Answer (score -1):

While starting a simulation, uncheck the box in the pop-up dialog box (as indicated by the black arrow). That worked for me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIWhS.jpg)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.